# Custom loss function in pytorch 1.10.1

Tags: pytorch, loss-function

I am struggeling with defining a custom loss function for pytorch 1.10.1. My model outputs a float ranging from -1 to +1. The target values are floats of arbitrary range. The loss should be a sum of pruducts if the sign between the model output and target is different.

I have searched the internet for quite some hours, but it seems there have been some changes to pytorch throughout the last versions, so I don't really know which example would best fit to my use case and pytorch 1.10.1.

Here is my approach so far:

```
class Loss(torch.nn.Module):
    @staticmethod
    def forward(self, output, target) -> Tensor:
        loss = 0.0
        
        for i in range(len(target)):
            o = output[i,0]
            t = target[i]
            l = o * t
            if l<0:   #if different sign
                loss -= l

        return loss
```

Question:

1. Should I subclass `torch.nn.Module` or `torch.autograd.Function`?
2. Do I need to define `@staticmethod`?
3. On some examples, I saw `ctx` instead of `self` being used and invocations of `ctx.save_for_backward` etc. Do I need this? What is its purpose?
4. When subclassing `torch.nn.Module`, my code complains: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'children'. What am I missing?
5. When subclassing `torch.autograd.Function`, my code complains about not having a backward function defined. How should my backward function look like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Custom loss functions can be as simple as a python function. You can simplify this a bit:

```
def custom_loss(output, target):
    prod = output[:,0]*target
    return -prod[prod<0].sum()
```

Comment: Thanks, my code runs with this. Is gradient calculation and optimiation then handled by pytorch? I folllow the example code in [link](https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/basics/optimization_tutorial.html)

Comment: Yes this is all handled automatically because of the graph nature of PyTorch. I just followed the code at [this link](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/custom-loss-functions/29387/2). Also, please accept and upvote if it solved your problem!